# TextAlign and Vertical Align won't work for one cell in table in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, text-alignment

I want to apply Center & Middle for **all cells** in this table, no condition need, just all cells in table.

This is what I do for each column:

[image: Modify Center & Middle for all columns]

And this is how preview comes out:

[image: The first column cannot be centered or Middle]

First I thought maybe it's because the data type for `DetailSheetNo` is `CHAR`, so its length is fixed, so I cast it to `VARCHAR`:

```
CAST(CastPieces.DetailSheetNo AS VARCHAR(50)) AS DetailSheetNo
```

But it's still not solved the problem.

I wonder what would be the reason.

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't that the data is padded with spaces? `RTRIM(CAST(CastPieces.DetailSheetNo AS VARCHAR(50)) ) AS DetailSheetNo`

Comment: Oh that's the problem! After RTRIM it's working :)  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I had the exact same problem and RTRIM() also solved it. Very subtle error.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the comments:
The problem might appear because the word rendered in the cell has to many char and therefor cannot fit in the cell properly.

Make sure the word doesn't countain a lot of white space at the end. If so, right click on the cell, then "Expression" then write something similar to this:

```
=RTRIM(Fields!MYFIELD.Value)
```